# Content Search query, filtering using managed meta data

Tags: 2013, search, filter, content

In a Sharepoint 2013 template, I'd like to get all contacts in a contact list filtered by their selected categories using Content Search. I do know how to get contacts based on a single value, but how about multiple values?

This works (ContactResponsibleProductCategoriesis a manage metadata field):

```
path:"url/lists/Contacts" ContactResponsibleProductCategories:{Page.OneProductCategory}
```

But how about several products?

```
path:"url/lists/Contacts" ContactResponsibleProductCategories:{Page.ManyProductCategories}
```

( {Page.ManyProductCategories} is a manage metadata field that contains products in the following format "Product A; Product C; Product X"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find a solution (seems to work only with managed metadata fields, not standard multiselect fields). Just add brackets around the whole expression and a single pipe | in the beginning like this:

```
path:"url/lists/Contacts" {|ContactResponsibleProductCategories:{Page.ManyProductCategories}}
```